# Button moving on a excel worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, excel-2013

There is any possibility to make the button on a excel worksheet to move alongside with me when while I am scrolling down.

Thank you,

Comment: Easy if you scroll with *ARROW* keys, not so easy if you scroll with scrollbars

Comment: Can you just freeze pane?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to make a Shape *(like a Button)* move as you move the activecell *(for example,using the ARROW keys)*.  Put the following code in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
        .Top = ActiveCell.Top
        .Left = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Left
    End With
End Sub
```